# How do I make a button go to a specific PivotItem on a PivotPage

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, pivotitem

I am making a Windows Phone 8 app.

I have a Panorama page in which I have 6 buttons (main.xaml). I created a new page (extras.xaml) within the same project which has 6 PivotItems. When I click Button 1 in panorama page it should go to the first pivot item in pivot page and when I click button 2 in panorama page it should go to the second pivot item in pivot page. I have been primarily developing in VB.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `navigation parameters` when navigating to `extras.xaml`. For button one set `pivotItem` (for example) to `1`, for button two set it to `2` and go on. To set a variable basically add it to your navigation URI (so `extras.xaml` becomes `extras.xaml?pivotItem=1`).

You may check out [Navigation Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring(v=vs.95).aspx) on MSDN to learn about handling in on `extras.xaml`.